# How to read remaining items in Channel<T> less than batch size, if there is no new items coming to channel within X minutes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, batching, system.threading.channels

I am using `Channel` from `System.Threading.Channels` and wants to read items in batch (5 items) and I have a method like below,

```
public class Batcher
{
    private readonly Channel<MeasurementViewModel> _channel;
    public Batcher()
    {
        _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<MeasurementViewModel>();
    }
    public async Task<MeasurementViewModel[]> ReadBatchAsync(int batchSize, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var result = new MeasurementViewModel[batchSize];

        for (var i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
            result[i] = await _channel.Reader.ReadAsync(stoppingToken);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and in ASP.NET Core background service I am using it like below,

```
public class WriterService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly Batcher _batcher;
    public WriterService(Batcher batcher)
    {
        _batcher = batcher;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var batchOfItems = await _batcher.ReadBatchAsync(5, stoppingToken);

            var range = string.Join(',', batchOfItems.Select(item => item.Value));

            var x = range;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is working and whenever there is 5 items in `Channel`, I am getting `range`.

Question is, when there are only 2 items left in `Channel` and since last 10 minutes NO items coming to `Channel`, then how to read the remaining 2 items in `Channel`?

Comment: An alternative solution could be to use the [`ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync) method, in combination with a [`Buffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661709/how-to-batch-an-iasyncenumerablet-enforcing-a-maximum-interval-policy-between "How to batch an IAsyncEnumerable<T>, enforcing a maximum interval policy between consecutive batches?") operator that has a `TimeSpan` argument.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, any example code can you share?

Comment: Inside the `ExecuteAsync` you could do this loop: `await foreach (var batchOfItems in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync().Buffer(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))) //...`

Comment: Thanks and appreciate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource) `CancellationTokenSource`, so that you can watch simultaneously for both an external cancellation request, and an internally induced timeout. Below is an example of using this technique, by creating a `ReadBatchAsync` extension method for the [`ChannelReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1) class:

```
public static async ValueTask<T[]> ReadBatchAsync<T>(
    this ChannelReader<T> channelReader,
    int batchSize, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(channelReader);
    if (batchSize < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchSize));
    if (timeout < TimeSpan.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeout));
    using CancellationTokenSource linkedCTS = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    linkedCTS.CancelAfter(timeout);
    List<T> buffer = new();
    while (true)
    {
        var token = buffer.Count == 0 ? cancellationToken : linkedCTS.Token;
        T item;
        try
        {
            item = await channelReader.ReadAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            break; // The cancellation was induced by timeout (ignore it)
        }
        catch (ChannelClosedException)
        {
            if (buffer.Count == 0) throw;
            break;
        }
        buffer.Add(item);
        if (buffer.Count >= batchSize) break;
    }
    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```

This method will produce a batch immediately after the specified `timeout` has elapsed, or sooner if the `batchSize` has been reached, provided that the batch contains at least one item. Otherwise it will produce a single-item batch as soon as the first item is received.

In case the channel has been completed by calling the `channel.Writer.Complete()` method, and it contains no more items, the `ReadBatchAsync` method propagates the same [`ChannelClosedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelclosedexception) that is thrown by the native `ReadAsync` method.

In case the external `CancellationToken` is canceled, the cancellation is propagated by throwing an `OperationCanceledException`. Any items that may have already been extracted internally from the `ChannelReader<T>` at this time, are lost. This makes the cancellation feature a **destructive** operation. It is advisable that the whole `Channel<T>` should be discarded after that.

Usage example:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        MeasurementViewModel[] batch;
        try
        {
            batch = await _channel.Reader.ReadBatchAsync(
                5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { return; }
        catch (ChannelClosedException) { break; }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', batch.Select(item => item.Value)));
    }
    await _channel.Reader.Completion; // Propagate possible failure
}
```

For an alternative approach of consuming a channel in batches, whose cancellation is non-destructive, you can look at this question:

- [How to batch a ChannelReader, enforcing a maximum interval policy between consuming and processing any individual item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313288/how-to-batch-a-channelreadert-enforcing-a-maximum-interval-policy-between-con)

Comment: Sir, you made my day. Excellent, Appreciated, Thanks  !!!!