# How to batch a ChannelReader<T>, enforcing a maximum interval policy between consuming and processing any individual item?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, producer-consumer, iasyncenumerable, system.threading.channels

I am using a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) in a producer-consumer scenario, and I have the requirement to consume the channel in batches of 10 items each, and without letting any consumed item to stay idle in a buffer for more than 5 seconds. This duration is the maximum latency allowed between reading an item from the channel, and processing a batch that contains this item. The maximum latency policy has precedence over the batch size policy, so a batch should be processed even with fewer than 10 items, in order to satisfy the max-latency requirement.

I was able to implement the first requirement, in the form of a `ReadAllBatches` extension method for the [`ChannelReader<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1) class:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T[]> ReadAllBatches<T>(
    this ChannelReader<T> channelReader, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> buffer = new();
    while (true)
    {
        T item;
        try { item = await channelReader.ReadAsync(); }
        catch (ChannelClosedException) { break; }
        buffer.Add(item);
        if (buffer.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return buffer.ToArray();
            buffer.Clear();
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Count > 0) yield return buffer.ToArray();
    await channelReader.Completion; // Propagate possible failure
}
```

I am planning to use it like this:

```
await foreach (Item[] batch in myChannel.Reader.ReadAllBatches(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing batch of {batch.Length} items");
}
```

**My question is:** how can I enhance my `ReadAllBatches<T>` implementation with an additional `TimeSpan timeout` parameter, that enforces the aforementioned maximum latency policy, and without installing third-party packages to my project?

**Important:** The requested implementation should not be susceptible to the memory leak issue that has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose). So the loop that consumes the channel should not cause the steady increment of the memory used by the application, in case the producer that writes the items in the channel has become idle for a prolonged period of time.

**Note:** I am aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661709/how-to-batch-an-iasyncenumerablet-enforcing-a-maximum-interval-policy-between) exists regarding batching the [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1) interface, but I am not interested to that. I am interested for a method that targets directly the `ChannelReader<T>` type, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an implementation of an idea that was posted [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/761#issuecomment-800558836), by [tkrafael](https://github.com/tkrafael).

> I had the same "leak" issue and resolved by:
>
> - First read uses main token (If I have no items to handle, just wait until one arrives)
> - All the remaining items must be read in x milliseconds
>
> This way I will never get an empty read due to timeout cancellation token (ok, maybe one empty read when application is being shutdown) and I get correct behaviour when items arrives from channel's writer.

The internal `CancellationTokenSource` is scheduled with a timer for cancellation, immediately after consuming the first element in the batch.

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads all of the data from the channel in batches, enforcing a maximum
/// interval policy between consuming an item and emitting it in a batch.
/// </summary>
public static IAsyncEnumerable<T[]> ReadAllBatches<T>(
    this ChannelReader<T> source, int batchSize, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (batchSize < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchSize));
    if (timeSpan < TimeSpan.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeSpan));
    return Implementation();

    async IAsyncEnumerable<T[]> Implementation(
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource timerCts = CancellationTokenSource
            .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            List<T> buffer = new();
            while (true)
            {
                CancellationToken token = buffer.Count == 0 ?
                    cancellationToken : timerCts.Token;
                (T Value, bool HasValue) item;
                try
                {
                    item = (await source.ReadAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false), true);
                }
                catch (ChannelClosedException) { break; }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
                    // Timeout occurred.
                    Debug.Assert(timerCts.IsCancellationRequested);
                    Debug.Assert(buffer.Count > 0);
                    item = default;
                }
                if (buffer.Count == 0) timerCts.CancelAfter(timeSpan);
                if (item.HasValue)
                {
                    buffer.Add(item.Value);
                    if (buffer.Count < batchSize) continue;
                }
                yield return buffer.ToArray();
                buffer.Clear();
                if (!timerCts.TryReset())
                {
                    timerCts.Dispose();
                    timerCts = CancellationTokenSource
                        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            // Emit what's left before throwing exceptions.
            if (buffer.Count > 0) yield return buffer.ToArray();

            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Propagate possible failure of the channel.
            if (source.Completion.IsCompleted)
                await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally { timerCts.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
await foreach (Item[] batch in myChannel.Reader
    .ReadAllBatches(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing batch of {batch.Length} items");
}
```

This implementation is non-destructive, meaning that no items that have been consumed from the channel are in danger of being lost. In case the enumeration is canceled or the channel is faulted, any consumed items will be emitted in a final batch, before the propagation of the error.

**Note:** In case the source [`ChannelReader<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1) is completed at the same time that the `cancellationToken` is canceled, the cancellation has precedence over completion. This is the same behavior with all native methods of the `ChannelReader<T>` and `ChannelWriter<T>` classes. It means that it's possible (although rare) for an `OperationCanceledException` to be thrown, even in case all the work has completed.

Comment: That was always a bug in the poster's code, not Channels. A Channel is an async queue that preserves the order of read requests. It's not meant to be polled. There's no "maximum" wait in an async queue - if the worker task isn't blocked, posted items will be processed immediately. Channels are used extensively in SignalR and .NET 7's HttpClient. If they had leaks, a *lot* of developers would have noticed

Comment: As for batching/windowing by time, the correct type is a Timer, not CancellationTokenSource. This problem was already solved in Rx.NET and the same techniques(even the same operators) can be used with channels and IAsyncEnumerable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is not the correct place to discuss about the undocumented leaky behavior of the built-in `Channel<T>` implementations, under specific usage pattern and circumstances. You could share your opinion in the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose) as an answer, which [you have already done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607759/11178549), [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669028/11178549), so I don't see the point of repeating yourself here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BTW I am glad that you participate in the [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/761 "Possible CancellationTokenRegistration leak in AsyncOperation<T>"). Which is more than two years old, and it's still undecided whether this behavior should be fixed or not (and subsequently whether it should be documented or not).

Comment: This isn't a discussion about a non-issue. It's a comment on an answer to the wrong problem, something that could cause harm to others. The *real* problem, buffering, is a lot easier to solve and doesn't require such complex code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you think that the question is wrong and harmful, you could consider posting your thoughts as an answer.

Comment: The answer would start with `channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync().ToObservable() .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ToAsyncEnumerable();`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you have already posted this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose/67669028#67669028). Apart from being a demonstrably flawed solution, it doesn't satisfy the requirement *"without installing third-party packages to my project"*. Please read the question carefully before answering.