# IAsyncEnumerable converted to IObservable (and Task) doesn't start

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, rx.net, iasyncenumerable

I have the following code in my `BackgroundService`:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await GetElements(cancellationToken)
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 100)
        .Select(elements => Observable.FromAsync(() => ProcessElementsAsync(
            elements, cancellationToken)))
        .Concat()
        .ToTask(cancellationToken);
}

private async IAsyncEnumerable<Element> GetElements(
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)  // <-- Breakpoint is here
    {
        yield return await _queue.DequeueElementAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the breakpoint is never hit. It looks as if the `GetElements` is never actually executed.

When I replace `ExecuteAsync` with this code, the breakpoint in `GetElements` does get hit:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    GetElements(cancellationToken)
        .ToObservable()
        .Subscribe(val =>
        {
            _ = 1;
        });

    await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, cancellationToken);
}
```

What's wrong with the first implementation?

Comment: Related question for context: [How to buffer a queue with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873568/how-to-buffer-a-queue-with-a-timeout)

Comment: I haven't used `Buffer` much but I wouldn't be surprised if that affects you not reaching the breakpoint. However more likely I think is that your Select statement is problematic. Can you use `SelectMany(this IObservable<TInput>, Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>>` instead?

Comment: As an aside, note that you should use the cancellation token that comes from `FromAsync`:  `.Select(elements => Observable.FromAsync(ct => ProcessElementsAsync(
            elements, ct)))`

Comment: Also I don't think you need to pass the cancellation token into GetElements -- that should be coming automatically from the ToObservable / "async enumerator infrastructure"

Comment: To sum up, I have found it best to really separate the "IObservable" pipelines from the "classic async" pipelines.  So I'd for example have a function that returns IObservable only (leave off the .ToTask).  Then if desired you can have a separate function that returns Task and takes in the cancellation token (or you can just use ToTask in the caller)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to how you are reading `GetElements`. Try something like
`await foreach (var element in GetElements())`.

I'm running unit tests and trying to hit a break point.

```
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> SomeFunc()
    {
        yield return true;
    }

    public async Task SomeFunc2()
    {
        await AwaitableFunc();
        return;
    }
```

And I can only hit a breakpoint in SomeFunc if I call it like this

```
await foreach (var item in SomeFunc()){}
```

Calling it like this does not hit the breakpoint

```
SomeFunc()
```

The code for IAsyncEnumerable functions doesn't execute immediately upon calling the method. Instead, it only starts executing when you begin iterating over the enumerable.